# Accessing files of root project from a react package (or from node_modules package) in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-package

I am trying to build a react package. In the package I want to access a json file (or multiple files from a folder) from src of the root project.

```
my_project  
|  
|----node_modules  
|    |  
|    |----my_package
|    |    |
|    |    |-----index.js //here i want to import file src/config.json
|    |
|----src
|    |----config.json
|    |----App.js
|----otherfile1
|----otherfile2
```

Really stuck on this for days.

Relative path option like "../../" from node_modules to src is not working

Also tried to use path library but not able to use that in react

Comment: If any random node_module package can access my project code that way I would be worried. Why not pass down the config to your package from the project itself where the package is being instantiated (used)?

Comment: This is a code design problem. It would be wrong for a dependent package (`my_package`) to reach into the thing depending on it. That would break basic expectations of encapsulation of packages. Packages are supposed to be reusable and not only work depending on what is depending on it. Instead, the `config.json` should be imported in the consumer and passed to a function that `my_package` exports.